# Selective attributes not displaying in GeoCortex Essential Manager

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fields-attributes, relates, geocortex, geocortex-essentials

I'm having trouble with Geocortex Essential Manager displaying the full set of attributes for a particular feature. Specifically, I have a parcels dataset and 4 related tables. I recently added a new subdivision into the base and filled out the related tables for the parcels.

Normally, I just need to reconcile my edits against the default and not touch GeoCortex Essential Manager and the changes will appear on the webmap. However this time only the geometry edits (parcel polygons and address points) went through and appeared in the webmap. The data in the tables was not viewable in the webmap.

I went back and checked the realtes in Arc and everything worked great, I've made sure all the changes were reconciled back to the default version on the database and I've been thru Geocortex and reviewed all the options and nothing seems to be off. Every other parcel in the base still has the full range of attributes associated with it.

Is there a lag time between edits being reconciled in Arc and the changes appearing in the webmap?

Answer (score 2):

There is no lag time, the data is not stored in Geocortex at all.  The data comes from a map service configured for use in a Geocortex app.

If the service was never updated after you changed the data schema, then that schema change would not be reflected in the service.

Essentials does hold configuration for its layers, obviously, and it would need to be updated with a schema change as well once the web service has been updated... if you were to try to configure a layer using the Rest Manager that hasn't been updated in the service you'll have a bad time.  Make sure that your service has the proper schema available at its rest endpoint, then update your GCE layers accordingly.

**Edit: I shouldn't say that geocortex doesn't store any data at all... it does store configured data when it indexes the instant search, but this does not affect the data seen in the app, for example in a details panel.

Comment: Most schema changes will be handled by Essentials Manager automatically.  However, if they cannot, then there will be a warning icon by your site title - if you click that icon you may be able to fix the issues that were detected.

Answer (score 0):

1st, Check that your edits are committed to base / versioning in ArcSDE (looks like they are if you see the newly added Parcel polygons).

With Geocortex, if a DataLink (Layer Info Query) fails, it simply returns nothing.  My guess is that the linking field (the field in common with your 4 related tables) is not updated.

The best thing to do is always to split the big issue into smaller ones to pin-point the source of the problem.   What happens if you ww w poliart c 0m run the SQL behind your DataLink into a SQL Client.   Run this script in isolation and replace the @FIELD with a known parcel number.

Next, make sure that the access is not blocked : is the SQL login still working OK?

Test each step in isolation.
 - Try consuming the map service from a simpler app like ArcGIS Portal or bring the map service in ArcMAP, and run an identify tool.  Does it show correct attributes for the newly modified Parcels?
 - Try looking at your REST end point URL and click "query" in 
[Supported Operations] or "identify", at the bottom of the page. Input a known parcel number and put a "*" in the attributes field. Does it show all the attribute fields?
 - Is the cadaster layer consumed as a feature service elsewhere and still in editing mode? (is some other user currently editing the cadaster layer in ArcMap and forgot to click "finish editing")?

If you need assistance, I am happy to remote into your system and have a look  [www.poliart.com](http://www.poliart.com)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have had some success this morning. I stopped the mapping services to compress and analyze the database. Once I had completed and restarted the mapping services 3 out of 4 of the related tables appeared in the webmap. Is this likely because of the compression or the restarting of the mapping services? Thanks

Comment: Hard to say. Compression can fix a few low-level problems in a db, but there can be "server burps" in a map service resolved by restarting the service.  When I see my data amiss in a web app, I usually head to the data service's REST endpoint first to see that data matches.  If the rest endpoint does not match, then it is a GCE issue.  If the service matches, then I check if the data itself matches on desktop.  If not, then its a service issue and I restart the service first, if problem persists check config second.  If the desktop data is bad, i compress first, then talk to the data steward.